# HTML & JS: stretching <canvas> content

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a `canvas` with some paths drawn on it. Is it possible to somehow manually stretch its content vertically?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you ellaborate what you mean by 'stretch' do you want to increate the heights? You can make the canvas height bigger, by using canvas.height, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey, I don't have any code, I just need the behaviour I described in the question, this is not "why isn't this code working?" question and there's nothing to reproduce

Comment: @Jean-Paul, I don't want to modify dimensions of the canvas, I want to actually stretch it content, move pixels so that any shape on it becomes longer or shorter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer: what I actually needed was `CanvasRenderingContext2D.scale(x, y)`

Comment: Can you accept your own answer so that this question is closed? :)